# Why does save screenshot sometimes block indefinitely in Selenium + headless Chrome + Python 2.7?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-headless

In my code, I save a screenshot prior to submitting a form via `element.submit()` and afterwards. I also have logging surrounding the call to `webdriver.save_screenshot()`. What I am seeing is that *sometimes* saving a screenshot blocks the process until I kill the `chromedriver` and/or `Chrome` processes.

This screenshot locking up Chrome happens on both **Mac OS X** and **Ubuntu 16.04** Server (AWS EC2). I have only been able to get this to repro on *headless* Chrome on the Mac.

Any thoughts or suggestions on why this would occur? My *guess* at this point is that it has to do with `element.submit()` because I have yet to see this happen except (immediately) after that call.

Comment: You can screenshot a headless browser? lol... that seems... odd in itself.

Comment: @NeilC.Obremski Update the question with the _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_ along with your code trials

Comment: @JeffC Yes, headless simply means the UI is not rendered not that the page is not processed. It's particularly useful when running on a computer (server) which *has* no graphical display such as an EC2 instance.

Comment: @Newcontributor 1. navigate to web page, 2. submit form, 3. save screenshot.

Comment: @NeilC.Obremski I understand what a headless browser is and how it works, I just wouldn't have expected that you could take a screenshot on a headless browser since there is no UI.

Comment: @JeffC It depends on what you mean by a UI. The browser still processes HTML and CSS to generate a page, it just doesn't render it visibly. Without a UI, there'd be no way to drive it when you send it commands like "click in the coordinates 50,100"

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an ideal solution but in order to keep from blocking indefinitely I've tapped into Python's `threading` module to take a screenshot like so:

```
import threading
t = threading.Thread(target=webdriver.get_screenshot_as_file, args=[fn])
t.start()
t.join(10)
assert not t.isAlive(), "Screenshot failed"
```

If an exception occurs then I quit or terminate the browser process which results in the thread dying off as well.